# Did the Google Webmaster +1 statistics move somewhere else or are they just gone?

Tags: google-search-console, google-plus

Google Webmaster used to have very nice statistics for a while. Then it was taken off. Did it move elsewhere? Or did it merely vanish?

Comment: I think it's just gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has removed the help pages about the +1 reports in Google Webmaster Tools.   This indicates to me that the feature is gone for good.

There are [still some vestiges](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96568?hl=en) in the help section, but which contain lots of broken links:

> +1 Reports provides insight into the effects of the Google +1 button on your site's traffic. Data is available for [Search Impact](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/answer.py?answer=1140189), [Activity](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/answer.py?answer=1140192), and [Audience](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/answer.py?answer=1198127).